# I got the json data false.

Tags: php, mysql, json

Here Is my PHP code to encode the JSON data from MySQL database. And this is my URL http://fwtest.ga/appoint.php; I tested on the online website JSONLint to validate my JSON data. It is valid, but I got the result [false] instead of the data in JSON format. Can anybody tell what am I doing wrong?

```
 <?php 

    $host = "my_host";
    $user = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $db = "db_name";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);

    $sql = "select time, date from table_name;";


    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)
     or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

    $response = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    array_push($response, array("time" >= $row[1], "date" >= $row[2]));


    }
    echo json_encode(array("server_response">= $response));
    echo (json_last_error()=== JSON_ERROR_UTF8);
    mysqli_close($con)

     ?>
```

Comment: You have a typo in `echo json_encode(array("server_response">= $response));`. Should be => not >=

Comment: Similarly in the `array_push()` call.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you're returning a single boolean here:

```
json_encode(array("server_response">= $response));
                                    ↑
```

That's not the array operator.